# Update JSON Array with React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Here is my JSON Array.

```
 rows : [
   { 
     "id":1,
     "first_name":"William",
     "last_name":"Elliott",
     "email":"welliott0@wisc.edu",
     "country":"Argentina",
     "ip_address":"247.180.226.89",
     "notificationType": [
       {
         "type": "update",
         "text": "New Update"
         "selected":null
       },
       {
         "type": "user",
         "text": "New User"
         "selected":null           
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

I need to update this array.For example let's take care of notificationType data.

I want to update "selected":null value to "selected":true.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through your data, e.g.:

```
var data = {
    rows: [ {
            'id': 1,
            'first_name': 'William',
            'last_name': 'Elliott',
            'email': 'welliott0@wisc.edu',
            'country': 'Argentina',
            'ip_address': '247.180.226.89',
            'notificationType': [
                { 'type': 'update', 'text': 'New Update', 'selected': null },
                { 'type': 'user', 'text': 'New User', 'selected': null }
            ]
        } 
    ]
};

data.rows.forEach(function(row) {
    row.notificationType.forEach(function(notif) {
        notif.selected = true;
    });
});
```

or if you want to update particular notification:

```
data.rows[0].notificationType[1].selected = true;
//--------^ row index
//----------------------------^ notification index
```